# Magento 2 - How show product price in dropdown choose an option

Tags: attributes, product, magento2, configurable-product, price

I want to show the product difference price in the dropdown list for configurable product (choose an option) same as in magento 1.X Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7200) in Magento 2

The JavaScript array which is used for the picklist is generated in the method `getJsonConfig()` in the Class

```
app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php
```

There you see two arrays added to `$config`: `attributes` and `optionPrices`.
`attributes` seems to contain the labels that are used for the dropdown.
`optionPrices` contains the prices which are used to refresh the price after a customer selects a different option (with a different price associated).

This will make it very difficult to show the price difference in the dropdown as the price difference values would need to be calculated in the JavaScript.

One solution that is relatively easy to implement would be something like this, but this will show the final price of each option, not the price difference:

- Create a Magento 2 plugin module that is triggered after the `getJsonConfig` is executed: `afterGetJsonConfig()`
- Then use the output of the `getJsonConfig` in `afterGetJsonConfig()`: `$config`, this array contains `attributes` and `priceOptions` array, amongst others.
- First jsondecode `$config`
- Then walk through the attributes array to determine the available options
- For each option, find the matching price in `priceOptions` array.
- Update each option label in the attributes array by concatenating the price (correctly formatted) to the existing label.
- jsonencode `$config`
- return `$config`